# Configure ng-animate speed

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have simply included the ngAnimate module, and now my ng-show elements are being animated when shown. Which is great.

But, the animation takes 1s (I think), how can I configure this to be another value, eg. .2s?

Answer (score 0):

It's done in the CSS (to adapt to your solution):

```
.animate-enter {
   -webkit-transition: 2s linear all; /* Chrome */
    transition: 2s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage animation timing from your css

```
.sample-show-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}
```